# Calculating top 4 of column 1 by column 2 - R

Tags: r, statistics

I'm new in R and to be honest don't know how to call what I'm looking  for :)

I have data-set "ds" set with 2 columns:

```
D  | res
==========
Ds  20
Dx  23
Dp  1
Ds  12
Ds  23
Ds  54
Dn  65
Ds  122
Dx  11
Dx  154
Dx  18
Do  4
Df  17
Dp  5
Dp  107
Dp  8
Df  3
Dp  33
Dd  223
Dc  7
Dv  22
Du  34
Dh  22
Ds  12
Dy  78
Dd  128
```

I need to calculate top 4 from column "D"  by "Res"  so desired result would look like :

```
D | Res
========
Dd  351
Dp  154
Ds  243
Dx  206
```

and by %age:

```
D  | % Of Total
==========
Dd  29.10%
Dp  12.77%
Ds  20.15%
Dx  17.08%
```

Thanks

Comment: Are these the sums ??

Comment: yes, first ones are sums and second ones percentages of total

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use aggregate() to obtain the sum of each type of "D", and we can introduce a new column to account for the edit of the OP and include also the percentage.

In order to display the result in the desired form, we can apply the order() function to rearrange the rows according to the value of Res. The function rev() in this case ensures that the highest value is put on top, and head() with the parameter 4 displays the first four rows.

```
summarized <- aggregate(Res ~. , df1, sum)
summarized$Perc <- with(summarized, paste0(round(Res/sum(Res)*100,2),"%"))
head(summarized[rev(order(summarized$Res)),],4)
   D  Res   Perc
2  Dd 351  29.1%
8  Ds 243 20.15%
11 Dx 206 17.08%
7  Dp 154 12.77%
```

**data**

```
df1 <- structure(list(D = structure(c(8L, 11L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 
8L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 6L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 7L, 2L, 1L, 10L, 9L, 
4L, 8L, 12L, 2L), .Label = c("Dc", "Dd", "Df", "Dh", "Dn", "Do", 
"Dp", "Ds", "Du", "Dv", "Dx", "Dy"), class = "factor"), Res = c(20L, 
23L, 1L, 12L, 23L, 54L, 65L, 122L, 11L, 154L, 18L, 4L, 17L, 5L, 
107L, 8L, 3L, 33L, 223L, 7L, 22L, 34L, 22L, 12L, 78L, 128L)), 
.Names = c("D", "Res"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -26L))
```

Comment: Nice solution, thanks,  I like to try follow build in R packages than following  new solutions with totally different way's to approach.  Cheers

Answer (score 2):

If you mean to sum `Res` per `D` and then select the top 4 sums (assuming you made mistakes calculating the sums for `ds` and `dp`) you could try:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% mutate(per = Res/sum(Res)) %>% group_by(D) %>% summarise(Res = sum(Res), perc = sum(per)) %>% top_n(4, Res)
Source: local data frame [4 x 3]

       D   Res      perc
  (fctr) (int)     (dbl)
1     Dd   351 0.2910448
2     Dp   154 0.1276949
3     Ds   243 0.2014925
4     Dx   206 0.1708126
```

Answer (score 1):

Option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
out = setorder(setDT(data)[, .(tmp = sum(res)), by = D]
                 [, .(D, ptg = (tmp/sum(tmp))*100)], -ptg)[1:4,]

#> out
#    D      ptg
#1: Dd 29.10448
#2: Ds 20.14925
#3: Dx 17.08126
#4: Dp 12.76949
```